# Ambiguous reference error when using iText for .NET

Tags: c#, pdf, fonts, itext

I am trying to write a form to help users make canned pdfs

im working with Itextsharp.dll and im walking through the tutorial [HERE](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/examples/Chap0201.cs) and I'm getting an error that seems to be over the keyword "FONT"

if I highlight over the first error I get

```
Error   1   'Font' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Drawing.Font' and 'iTextSharp.text.Font'
```

I understand that they both have a keyword font but it's unclear to me how to proceed to fix this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the error is on this line from your link:

```
Font[] fonts = new Font[14];
```

You need to specify which Font you mean, the one from the `System.Drawing` namespace or the one from `iTextSharp.text` namespace.  If you mean from the `iTextSharp.text` namespace, change the line to this:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font[] fonts = new iTextSharp.text.Font[14];
```

On the example the following lines require referencing the Font object from the System.Drawing namespace:

```
fonts[0] = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 12, Font.NORMAL);
```

You'll need to update these like so:

```
fonts[0] = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 12, System.Drawing.Font.NORMAL);
```